# OpenGL + ffmpeg slow in fullscreen mode

Tags: c++, opengl, ffmpeg, sdl

I'm trying to play a video file using ffmpeg and OpenGL + SDL. The playback is very slow and flickering. The code is an accumulation from different blogs/sites and I'm not really very sure what is going on. Sorry to post such a long code but this is the minimized version. My actual code does not play well in windowed mode also. Somehow the version below plays smoothly in windowed mode.

```
#ifndef INT64_C
#define INT64_C(c) (int64_t)(c)
#define UINT64_C(c) (uint64_t)(c)
#endif

extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}
#include <SDL.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

int fullscreen = 1, videoStream = -1, frameFinished=0;
const PixelFormat CONV_FORMAT = PIX_FMT_RGB24;
const char *fname = "moviesample.mp4";
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
AVCodecContext  *pCodecCtx = NULL;
AVCodec         *pCodec = NULL;
AVFrame         *pFrame = 0, *pFrameRGB = 0; 
AVPacket        packet;
AVDictionary    *optionsDict = NULL;
struct SwsContext *sws_ctx = NULL;
GLuint texture_video;

void av_init();
void draw_frame();

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  SDL_Event event;

  av_init();

  uint16_t width = fullscreen ? 1600 : pCodecCtx->width;
  uint16_t height = fullscreen ? 900 : pCodecCtx->height;

  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );
  SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, 32,
      SDL_OPENGL | SDL_HWPALETTE  | SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_HWACCEL | 
      (fullscreen ? SDL_FULLSCREEN : 0)
      );

  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glClearColor(0.0f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
  glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
  glLoadIdentity( );
  glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH );
  glGenTextures(1, &texture_video);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_video); 
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 
      0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pFrameRGB->data[0]);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

  sws_ctx = sws_getCachedContext(sws_ctx, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 
      pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, CONV_FORMAT, 
      SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  while (1) {

    draw_frame();

    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

    SDL_PollEvent(&event);

    switch(event.type) {
      case SDL_QUIT:
        SDL_Quit();
        exit(0);
        break;
      case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE) {
          SDL_Quit();
          exit(0);
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

void draw_frame() {
  if (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0) { 
    if(packet.stream_index==videoStream) {
      avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);
      if(frameFinished) {
        sws_scale (sws_ctx, (uint8_t const * const *)pFrame->data, 
            pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, pFrameRGB->data, 
            pFrameRGB->linesize);
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_video );
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, pCodecCtx->width, 
            pCodecCtx->height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pFrameRGB->data[0]);
      }

      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      glScalef(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
      glBegin(GL_QUADS);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); 
      glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
      glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
      glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
      glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
      glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
      glEnd();
      glScalef(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    }
    av_free_packet(&packet);
  } else {
    av_seek_frame(pFormatCtx, videoStream, 0,  AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME);
  }

}

void av_init() {
  av_register_all();
  avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, fname, NULL, NULL);
  avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL);
  for(uint8_t i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
    if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
      videoStream=i;
      break;
    }
  pCodecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;
  pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
  avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, &optionsDict);
  pFrame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
  pFrameRGB = avcodec_alloc_frame();
  int bytes = avpicture_get_size(CONV_FORMAT, pCodecCtx->width, 
    pCodecCtx->height);          
  uint8_t *video_buffer = (uint8_t*)av_malloc( bytes * sizeof(uint8_t) );
  avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, video_buffer, CONV_FORMAT,
      pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);
}
```

Comment: You use glBegin/glEnd calls with the exact same parameters each loop. This uploads the vertex buffers from CPU to GPU each frame, which had overhead. You could create two vertex buffers (one for position and one for texture coordinates) which will reside on the GPU, so there is no wasteful copy each frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fullscreen you're probably getting vsync, which means `SDL_GL_SwapBuffers()` will block for 16ms or so every frame.

To simulate the effect in windowed mode add a `SDL_Delay(16)` at the end of your main `while(1)` loop.

Rewrite `draw_frame()` so that it pumps `libav` *until* it gets the next frame, instead of just pumping it once per main loop and *hoping* you get a frame:

```
// g++ main.cpp `pkg-config sdl gl libswscale libavcodec libavformat --libs --cflags` && SDL_VIDEO_FULLSCREEN_HEAD=0 ./a.out
#ifndef INT64_C
#define INT64_C(c) (int64_t)(c)
#define UINT64_C(c) (uint64_t)(c)
#endif

extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}
#include <SDL.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

int fullscreen = 1, videoStream = -1, frameFinished=0;
const PixelFormat CONV_FORMAT = PIX_FMT_RGB24;
const char *fname = "/home/genpfault/vid.mpg";
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
AVCodecContext  *pCodecCtx = NULL;
AVCodec         *pCodec = NULL;
AVFrame         *pFrame = 0, *pFrameRGB = 0; 
AVPacket        packet;
AVDictionary    *optionsDict = NULL;
struct SwsContext *sws_ctx = NULL;
GLuint texture_video;

void av_init();
void next_frame();

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  SDL_Event event;

  av_init();

  uint16_t width = fullscreen ? 1920 : pCodecCtx->width;
  uint16_t height = fullscreen ? 1200 : pCodecCtx->height;

  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );
  SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, 32,
      SDL_OPENGL | 
      (fullscreen ? SDL_FULLSCREEN : 0)
      );

  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glClearColor(0.0f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
  glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
  glLoadIdentity( );
  glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH );
  glGenTextures(1, &texture_video);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_video); 
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 
      0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pFrameRGB->data[0]);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

  sws_ctx = sws_getCachedContext(sws_ctx, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 
      pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, CONV_FORMAT, 
      SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  while (1) {

    while( SDL_PollEvent(&event) )
    {
        switch(event.type) {
          case SDL_QUIT:
            SDL_Quit();
            exit(0);
            break;
          case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE) {
              SDL_Quit();
              exit(0);
            }
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
    }

    next_frame();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_video );
    glScalef(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); 
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();
    glScalef(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
  }
  return 0;
}

void next_frame() 
{
    while( true )
    {
        if( av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0 ) 
        { 
            if( packet.stream_index == videoStream ) 
            {
                avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);
                if(frameFinished) 
                {
                    sws_scale (sws_ctx, (uint8_t const * const *)pFrame->data, 
                    pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, pFrameRGB->data, 
                    pFrameRGB->linesize);
                    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_video );
                    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
                    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
                    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
                    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, pCodecCtx->width, 
                    pCodecCtx->height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pFrameRGB->data[0]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            av_free_packet(&packet);
        } 
        else 
        {
            av_seek_frame(pFormatCtx, videoStream, 0,  AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME);
        }        
    }
}

void av_init() {
  av_register_all();
  avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, fname, NULL, NULL);
  avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL);
  for(uint8_t i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
    if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
      videoStream=i;
      break;
    }
  pCodecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;
  pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
  avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, &optionsDict);
  pFrame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
  pFrameRGB = avcodec_alloc_frame();
  int bytes = avpicture_get_size(CONV_FORMAT, pCodecCtx->width, 
    pCodecCtx->height);          
  uint8_t *video_buffer = (uint8_t*)av_malloc( bytes * sizeof(uint8_t) );
  avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, video_buffer, CONV_FORMAT,
      pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! it works :) Is there a leak in the `next_frame` if the the stream is not videoStream, or frameFinished is true? These conditions skip the `av_free_packet` call.

Comment: Eh, could be :)  Not much of a `libav` guy.